# DebugElement is undefined in angular2 test

Tags: angular

I am trying angular2 testing first time.

```
  let component: AlertButtonComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AlertButtonComponent>;
  let de:DebugElement;

  it('should have an H1 tag of `Alert Button`' ,() => {
    console.log('debug element',de)
    expect(de.query(By.css('h1')).nativeElement.innerText).toBe('lert Button')
  })
```

I am getting error `typeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined` also **de** is `undefined`.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Check here : https://angular.io/guide/testing - testing in angular

Checked on angular website that you need to setup as below , if you are testing component `BannerComponent`, id dont see that kind of setup in you code

```
 let comp:    BannerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BannerComponent>;
  let de:      DebugElement;
  let el:      HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BannerComponent ], // declare the test component
    });

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance
// query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
```

---

Well error says that  `let de:DebugElement;` is undefined means you need to initialize it. something like

```
 let de:DebugElement = new DebugElement();
```

or  you have to pass service reference if you are using.

Comment: @raju - please check link of angular , you missed some information , check the link and include things here

Comment: @raju - point you missed is this line fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);, is that worked for you

Comment: @raju - if you go throgh this  https://angular.io/guide/testing  you find BannerComponent having h1 as part of template..which means in your case if it not present than it will give you error ...so i suggest better you follow the way , dont do copy paste

Comment: Actually in my case I forgot import { By }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

Comment: @raju - ok ..so if you issue is resolve than you upvote/accept answer